# Как группировать checkbox по name?

Tags: javascript

Как группировать `checkbox` по `name`?

Получаю `a[0]=1&a[1]=2&a[2]=3&b[3]=1&b[4]=2&c[5]=1&c[6]=2`
Как можно получить типа так?

> a[0]=1&a[1]=2&a[2]=3&b[0]=1&b[1]=2&c[0]=1&c[1]=2

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function(e) {
  var serialize = '',
    checkbox = e.target.form.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
  for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; ++i) {
    if (checkbox[i].type === 'checkbox' && checkbox[i].checked) {
      serialize += '&' + checkbox[i].name + '[' + i + ']=' + checkbox[i].value;
    }
  }
  console.log(serialize.substr(1));
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="form">
  <input type="checkbox" name="a" value="1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="a" value="2" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="a" value="3" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="b" value="1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="b" value="2" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="c" value="1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="c" value="2" />
  <button>Go</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сначала из перечисления делаем массив, затем его сортируем.

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function(e) {
  var serialize = '';
  var checkboxAll = e.target.form.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');

  var checkboxArray = Array.from(checkboxAll);
  checkboxArray = checkboxArray.sort((x, y) => { return x.name.localeCompare(y.name) });

  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxArray.length; ++i) {
    if (checkboxArray[i].type === 'checkbox' && checkboxArray[i].checked) {
      serialize += '&' + checkboxArray[i].name + '[' + i + ']=' + checkboxArray[i].value;
    }
  }
  console.log(serialize.substr(1));
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="form">
  <input type="checkbox" name="a" value="1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="a" value="2" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="a" value="3" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="b" value="1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="b" value="2" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="c" value="1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="c" value="2" />
  <button>Go</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо но не работает `a[0]=1&a[1]=2&a[2]=3&b[3]=1&b[4]=2&c[5]=1&c[6]=2`

Comment: Не получается так `a[0]=1&a[1]=2&a[2]=3&b[0]=1&b[1]=2&c[0]=1&c[1]=2`